# In Magento2, how can we use or embed the custom CSS?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

How can we add custom CSS file in the Magento 2 application globally or on the specific pages i.e Product page or Checkout page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add custom CSS to your module you need to include css in your Layout XML file under  section.

**To include css globally, add it to default.xml or for specific file add it to your desired file (ex. catalog_category_view.xml)**

Code to add in XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
   <head>
      <css src="css/yourcssfilename.css" />
 </head>
</page>
```

Now you need to create a css file which you defined in your XML file.

Create CSS file at **app/code/vendorName/moduleName/view/frontend/web/css/yourcssfilename.css**

**yourcssfilename.css**

```
#your CSS code
```

Run below commands and check:

> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Check it in documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html#fedg_css-in-themes_xml, example:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```